# Iterating properties in Properties.Settings.Default

Tags: c#, visual-studio, application-settings

I've got a Visual Studio project that contains a few StringCollections under app settings. I want to iterate over these properties/settings at runtime but can't find a way to do so. I've tried this:

```
foreach (SettingsProperty prop in Properties.Settings.Default.Properties)
   string className = (prop.DefaultValue as StringCollection)[1];
```

But `prop.DefaultValue` is not a `StringCollection` and returns null. I realize I can use `Properties.Settings.Default["SettingName"]` but that requires me to know the setting name beforehand. There has to be a way to iterate through the application setting names and read their associated `StringCollection` values, but how? I can't find an example after hours of searching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using

```
if(Properties.Settings.Default[prop.Name] is StringCollection sc){
    ...
}
```

in your loop?

Comment: Ok that works. Just seems like there would be a more efficient way since it's a collection and all.

Comment: There probably is. But I would guess that this is not a performance sensitive part of the code. There is no need optimizing if it will not make a measurable change.

Comment: By more efficient I meant easier to code, not faster to run.